# $10^n - 1 = 9k^4$, where $n$ and $k$ belong to $\mathbb{Z}$ (integers). How can one determine the number of solutions for $(n, k)$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, integers

The question above is a simplified form of a Mathematics Olympiad question for grade 11 (aged 16) students.

We do know of one solution which is: (1, 1). The students were asked to find if there are more than 1 solution. Given the fact that only basic mathematical theories have been taught to them, I am hoping for a fairly simple proof.

I have tried to solve the equation but had no idea where to start. I suspect there might be a technique that I am unaware of.

Could someone guide how to approach this equation and determine the number of solutions for $(n, k)$? Any insights, explanations, or hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: $(0,0), (1, -1)$ are also solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Olympiad-style Solution:

We claim that the only solutions are the only solutions are $(n, k)=(1,1)$, $(1, -1)$ or $(0, 0)$. Clearly, these satisfy the conditions. Now, we shall prove that they are the only solutions.

First, it can be easily verified that $4$th powers must be congurent to $0$ or $1$ modulo $8$.

When $n\geq3$, we have $\dfrac{10^n-1}{9}\equiv111\equiv3\pmod8$. Hence, there are no solutions for $n\geq3$.

When $n=2$, we have $\dfrac{10^n-1}{9}=11$, which does not work.

When $n=1$, we have $\dfrac{10^n-1}{9}=1$, which implies that $(n, k)=(1, 1)$ or $(1, -1)$ are possible solutions.

When $n=0$, we have $\dfrac{10^n-1}{9}=0$, which implies that $(n, k)=(0, 0)$ is a possible solution.

When $n<0$, $\dfrac{10^n-1}{9}<0$, but $\forall k\in\mathbb{Z},9k^4\geq0$, so there are no solutions for $n\leq0$.

Hence, the only solutions are $(n, k)=(1,1)$, $(1, -1)$ or $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Can downvoter explain why? Such lack of sportsmanship.

Comment: Downvotes happen for all kinds of reasons. Generally I ignore them unless someone has provided an explanation (or there are a ton of them).

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $n \ge 1$, the value $\frac{10^n - 1}{9}$ is the $n$-digit [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit).  So then, which repunits are perfect fourth powers?

It can be shown that the last two base-ten digits of a fourth power must be in the set $\{ 00, 01, 16, 21, 25, 36, 41, 56, 61, 76, 81, 96 \}$.  Note that 11 is **not** in this set, and since any repunit with two are more digits ends in 11,  there are no solutions for $n \ge 2$.

However, $n = 1$ gives us $k^4 = 1$, or $k = \pm 1$.  And $n = 0$ gives us $k = 0$.

Finally, $n < 0$ gives us $10^n - 1$ being a negative fraction, while $9k^4$ is a nonnegative integer, so the two sides of the equation can't be equal for $n < 0$.

Thus, the only possible solutions are:

- $n = 1, k = 1$
- $n = 1, k = -1$
- $n = 0, k = 0$

Comment: @IraeVid: Fine, I've written it.

Comment: Probably the simplest explanation. How do we know that the last 2 digits of forth powers form a finite set?

Answer (score 1):

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, show what you've tried.

- Show that there are no solutions to $ a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.
- Show that for $n \geq 2$, $\frac{10^m - 1 } { 9 } \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.
- Hence, there are no solutions for $n \geq 2$.
- Check what solutions are there for $n = 0, 1$.